# how to use "background-size : contain" in shorthand property with background with url.?

Tags: css

below css is working with contain as it 's separately given as **background-size** but not by using the shorthand given in background

even i also eager to know the **the parameters' sequence for background** property in CSS

```css
body { 
    background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size:contain,contain; 
}

 body { 
    background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat contain,contain fixed center; 
}  

but this is not working as i tried this shorthand method as above
```

```html
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
```

there is not an issue to use separately but need to know that whether any way to use **background-size:contain** in shorthand **background** property

even you can just check it out by making change in W3School's example here is the url for it

**[click to check your way](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center / contain;
```

this should work.

Comment: yup it's working i want to know what's there "/" here.?

Comment: According to W3C documentation(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-size) background-size should come after background-position property separated with a slash(/).

Comment: this is good i am just exploring the stackoverflow questions and from one question i just tried to use like this but was unable to so that so asked a question

Comment: it will be helpful if you can mark the answer correct if you found it to be correct and upto your expectation.